# Problem on conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with $E(X_1)=\frac{15}{4}$.
>
> If $\psi:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ is defined through the conditional expectation $\psi(t)=E(X_1^2\mid X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2=t),t>0$.
>
> Then what is the value of $E(\psi((X_1+X_2)^2))$ ?

I don't know how to approach this problem. Please help.

Comment: This is a problem in parsing the levels of the probability/expected value expressions.  Note that $\psi(t)$ is defined as a scalar function of $t$, so in itself is is not a "random" expression.  When you substitute $t=(X_1+X_2)^2$, the result will depend on random variables.  However the $X_1,X_2$ that appear here are not the same as the random variables with similar names that appear in the definition of $\psi$ because *those* appearances are "bound" by the expected value operator.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since the r.v. are independent and identically distributed, then by symmetry:

$$\mathsf E(X_1^2\mid X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2=t){~=~\mathsf E(X_2^2\mid X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2=t)\\~=~\mathsf E(X_3^2\mid X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2=t)}$$